# Automate HTML5 banner ads

Tags: html, image, crop, banner

I have a play to build out multiple HTML5 ads at the same time. Currectly using adobe Animate CC.. hate it.

Plan is to hard code it onto a html5 page and use CSS. I will have a page full of divs all at the correct ad size. Then say I use a background image in the css for all backgrounds centered and set to cover.

Is there anyway to have it crop and download the correct image sizes based on the div size??? I want it to download at 100% view and crop based on the div width and height. This way I use a single image, position it with css for all the banner sizes and run some code to give me all of the sizes correctly based on the div.

HELP!